# How to fit optimal rectangles to an area under a curve (data points)

Tags: python, optimization, curve

Having a set of datapoints and a given number n, I want to find the dimensions and coordinates of n number of rectangles, that fit optimally the area under the curve. This is probably an optimization (minimization) problem where:
**Loss function** -> [sum{1 to n}(wi*hi)] - [Area Under the Curve]
wi: is the width of rectangle i
hi: is the height of rectangle i

The problem that occurs is that when I use n>1 (meaning more than one rectangles) the solution returns rectangles that are not correct and definitely not sequential. using n=1 returns however the correct rectangle 
In code using python and scipy.optimize, I use the following code:

## Define your data points for the curve

```
x_data = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

y_data = x_data*3+2
```

## Define the objective function to minimize

```
def objective_function(dimensions):
    # Dimensions is a 1D array containing the heights and x-axis points of the blocks
    # Split dimensions into height and width arrays
    heights = dimensions[:n] #the first n values are the heights
    x = dimensions[n:] #the rest values are the points of the blocks on the x-axis
    
    widths=[x[i]-x[i-1] for i in range(1,len(x))]}
    
    # Calculate the area under the curve from the datapoints
    area_under_curve = np.trapz(y_data, x_data)#np.interp(widths, x_data, y_data), widths)

    # Calculate the difference between the total block area and the area under the curve
    difference = np.abs(np.sum(heights*widths) - area_under_curve)
    
    #Calculate the error between the height of each block and the respective datapoint of the 
    #curve
    dy =[(heights[i] - np.mean( y_data[round(x[i]):round(x[i+1])]  ))**2 for i in range(n)]
    height_difference = np.array(dy).sum() #np.interp(cumulative_widths[i], x_data, y_data) for i 
    in range(n)]

    # print('\n\n',x,'\n',widths,'\n',np.sum(heights*widths), area_under_curve)#, heights*widths)
    print(difference)
    difference+=height_difference

    return difference #
```

## Set the number of blocks

```
n = 7

np.random.seed(15)
# Initial guess for the dimensions (height and width) of the blocks
initial_dimensions = np.array([i+1+np.random.rand() for i in range (2*n+1)])
initial_dimensions[n]=0 #make sure first x equals zero
```

## Bounds for the dimensions

```
bounds = [(-0.0001, None)] * (2*n+1)  # No negative values for heights or xs
```

## Constraints to ensure xi>xi-1

```
serial_x_constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda dimensions, i=i: dimensions[n+1+i] - dimensions[n+i]} for i in range(n)]
```

## Additional constraints for the first and last block

```
constraint_first_block = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda dimensions: dimensions[n] - 0}  # x1 of the first block equals 0
constraint_last_block = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda dimensions: dimensions[-1] - x_data[-1]}  # last x equals the last x of the datapoints
```

## Combine all constraints into a single list

```
all_constraints = [constraint_total_width]  + equal_x_constraints + [constraint_first_block, constraint_last_block] + non_negative_x_constraints
```

## Run the optimization with the constraints

```
result = minimize(objective_function,
                initial_dimensions,
                bounds=bounds,
                constraints=serial_x_constraints,#[constraint_first_block, constraint_last_block]+serial_x_constraints,
                method='SLSQP'
                )
```

## Extract the optimal dimensions from the result

```
optimal_dimensions = result.x
```

## Plot the curve

```
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Curve')
plt.xlabel('Width')
plt.ylabel('Height')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Curve and Blocks')
plt.show()
```

#print optimal results heights and xs

```
print(optimal_dimensions)
```

Comment: Soon I will improve the problem formulation and presentation as well as add few examples and outputs. Thnx :)